# Apache Pig: Error 2103 Doing work on doubles

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation, we'll call A, that looks like this

```
--------------------------------
id     page      item    paid
--------------------------------
1      pdp       A
1      pdp       B
1      chekcout  B       9.99
2      pdp       C
2      checkout  C       100.00
```

I am trying to group by id and page and then sum the paid column, using something like

```
grpd   = GROUP A BY (id, page);
return = FOREACH grpd GENERATE FLATTEN(group), SUM(A.paid) AS total_paid:float;
```

The operation runs but when I `illustrate` or `dump`, Pig throws the error

> Error 2103: Problem doing work on Doubles

I am assuming that Pig is having problems because the `SUM()` where page is pdp is always `NULL` but when page is checkout, the `SUM()` will be of type `float`.  I tried using the ternary operator, something like, ....

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (price IS NULL ? 0 : price);
```

to fill in the `NULL`'s with zeros but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with NULL values as 
[SUM](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html%23sum) will automatically ignore them.

My guess is that your problem is with the way you LOAD data and that you want the result as float. Have you specified data types when you LOAD the data?

If you haven't specified the data type, Pig will automatically use double as [data type](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html%23data-types). Then SUM will use also double data type with the result.

Probably DUMP and ILLUSTRATE can't handle the data type conversion from double to long.

Try to specify data type of paid as float when you LOAD the data or change the data type of total_paid to double.